# When should the perfect tenses be used?

Tags: grammar-choice, meaning

No matter the language, it seems as if the perfect tenses (except for the future perfect) can be replaced with the imperfect. In translation, why do these sets of tenses have different meaning? I don't understand their difference other than the way they're worded.

Sometimes, I see example sentences on dictionary sites with translations aside them. They'll have an English imperfect rendered by a Latin perfect/pluperfect. Are there situations in which a phrase should be translated in a different tense than its equivalent in another language?

Comment: Can you add an example where a Latin perfect can be replaced with an imperfect, and an example where someone rendered an English imperfect with a Latin perfect or pluperfect?

Comment: Yes, give an example sentence or two. Also, say what dictionary site you are using. There's a lot of misinformation and inaccurate translation out there.

Comment: You know, my teacher a while back would often do this while translating poetry. We'd encounter an imperfect tense in Latin and then translate it into a perfect tense. This may be poetic license, but it was also done during the translation of prose, so I'm interested to see if there is some sort of reason, or if it is merely a mistake.

Comment: I don't know of any construction in English called the "English imperfect". The English "simple past" tense (like "I walked") can be used to convey either an imperfective or perfective meaning. Is that what you are talking about in the last paragraph?

Comment: @sumelic The English imperfect (one form of it, anyway) is _used to,_ as in "We used to learn Latin by the grammar-translation method, before we wised up." Regardless, we need an example or two or three to be clear on what this question is asking about.

Comment: @MiddleSchoolHistorian Can you add some examples in your question and try to explain it more? This sounds like an interesting question, but unclear and therefore unanswerable without some elaboration.

Comment: Thanks to my horrible luck, I can't find any examples, but I remember finding quite a bit of these instances on en.glosbe.com. If anybody luckier than I can encounter some of them, please comment! They were rather frequent, and were very simple; I'm not talking about lengthy passages loosely translated.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few tricky points here.

The key is the **tense-aspect distinction**: Latin "tenses" really represent a combination of time and *aspect*.

Latin has three aspects, inherited from Proto-Indo-European:

- The **imperfective aspect** is for when the duration is important: the action is continuing, or habitual, or going on for a long time.
- The **aoristic aspect** is for when the duration is unimportant: you can think of the action as a single point in time.
- The **perfective aspect** is for when the action is over and done, but its consequences are important at the moment.

It also has three tenses, which didn't exist in PIE but were invented in Proto-Italo-Celtic:

- The **past tense** is about the past.
- The **present tense** is about right now.
- The **future tense** is about the future.

Now, each of the Latin "tenses" represents a pair (or multiple pairs) of these:

- The Latin **present** is **present imperfective** and **present aorist**: talking about right now, actions that are still going on, or duration doesn't matter.
- The Latin **imperfect** is **past imperfective**: talking about the past, actions that have a long duration or are habitual.
- The Latin **perfect** is **past aoristic** and **present perfective**: either talking about the past, actions where duration doesn't matter, *or* talking about completed actions that impact the *present*.
- The Latin **pluperfect** is **past perfective**: talking about completed actions that impact the *past*.
- The Latin **future** is **future imperfective** and **future aoristic**: talking about the future, actions that will have a long duration, or where duration doesn't matter.
- The Latin **future perfect** is **future perfective**: in the future, some already-completed action will be having an impact.

English is, formally, somewhat similar:

- "Have" + past participle makes a verb perfective.
- "Be" + present participle makes a verb imperfective.
- Using neither makes a verb aoristic.
- "Will" + infinitive makes a verb future.
- A special ending (usually *-ed*, sometimes not) makes a verb past.
- Using neither makes a verb present.

So by combining these, we can distinguish all nine combinations in ways Latin can't: Latin can't distinguish "he will be working" (future imperfective) from "he will work" (future aoristic), for instance.

But on the other hand, **the distinctions aren't mandatory** in English. The only distinction that's actually *mandatory* in English is **past versus non-past**, with everything else being optional. For example, "I hope it goes well" and "when we get home" both use a "present" form for a future action—because the context makes it clear that this non-past form is meant to be future, and extra words are unnecessary.

So when translating from English to Latin, a translator needs to take the context into account and figure out exactly which tense-aspect combination is actually meant for each verb—and when translating from Latin to English, they need to use English-speaking intuition to figure out how much of the tense actually needs to be specified. A sentence like "after he will have gotten the job, he should negotiate his paycheck" is *technically* correct English, but the "after" and "should" make it clear that future perfective is meant, so a native speaker would simplify it to "after he gets the job" (specifying only the mandatory "non-past" and letting context do the rest).

EDIT: [Later Latin also had a special "true perfect" tense](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10769/406) which separates out the *present perfective* meaning, leaving the normal "perfect" for *past aoristic*.

Answer (score 0):

So, the past tenses are quite interesting, and they have to do with the duration of the action.

**Imperfect** tense deals with **continuing actions** that happened in the **past**:

> *Hic **incolebam***. I used to live here.
>   *Ibi **sedēbam**.* I was sitting there.

**Perfect** tense deals with **remote** or **completed actions** that happened in the **past**:

> *Ibi **fuī**.* I have been there.
>   *Illud **fēcī**.* I have done that.

Then there is the **past-perfect** or **pluperfect** tense which deals with actions in the **distant past**, use especially when talking about a prior event or action relative to a past event or action (see comment below):

> *Illud **fēceram**.* I had done that.

**Future-perfect** deals with actions that are **expected to be completed by some time in the future**:

> *Tunc **decesserit**.* He will have left by then.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have a source regarding the pluperfect being about the "distant past"? I've never heard it explained that way.

Comment: Latin class at Walnut. The book we used was *Latin for Americans.*

Comment: *Ita, in viā ībam, et laciniam, quam in televisione vīderam, in fenestrā vīdī, et eam ēmī.* So, I was walking down the street, and I saw a dress, which I had seen on television (before then), in the window, and I bought it.

Comment: That example is fine. But I think the way it's currently worded gives the (incorrect) impression that the pluperfect means "a *really* long time ago." In fact, it just means "sometime before another past action." Virgil wouldn't have used *Urbs antiqua fuerat* even if Carthage had existed in the more distant past.

Comment: I use "distant past" rather loosely here.